# Куда залить файлы плагина?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Плагин TipTip jQuery для WordPress.

Куда залить в WordPress файлы плагина TipTip jQuery:
jquery.tipTip.js, tipTip.css? Или же создать для этих файлов отдельную директорию?

Answer (score 1):

/wp-content/themes/mythemes/
Чтобы потом не запутаться в путях, заливайте в корень темы.